# If $S_{1},S_{2}$ be subsets of complex numbers then $\inf\lbrace |z_{1} - z_{2}| \rbrace > 0\; (z_{1} \in S_{1}\text{ and }z_{2} \in S_{2})$.

Tags: complex-numbers, compactness

Problem: "Suppose that $S_{1}$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb C$ (complex numbers) and  $S_{2}$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb C$(complex numbers). If $S_{1} \cap S_{2} = \varnothing$, then show that $\inf\lbrace |z_{1} - z_{2}| \rbrace  > 0\; (z_{1} \in S_{1}\text{ and }z_{2} \in S_{2})$".

I supposed that $A=\lbrace|z_{1} - z_{2}| : z_{1} \in S_{1} , z_{2} \in S_{2} \rbrace $ and $a = \inf A$.

If $a \in A$ then $a > 0$.
For "If $a \notin A$" I can't show that $a > 0$. Can you help me? Or have you another way for this problem? Can I solve this problem using Heine-Borel theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\inf\{|z-y|:\textrm{ }z\in S_1, y\in S_2\}=0$, so we can find a sequence $(z_n)$ on $S_1$ and a sequence $(y_n)$ on $S_2$ such that $|z_n-y_n|\rightarrow 0$, now use the compactness of $S_1$ and that $S_2$ is closed to show that there is a point on $S_1\cap S_2$ this show the result.

Comment: That's OK, thanks.